# Pass additional props to a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know how to pass additional props to an already defined React component, or if it is possible at all.

For instance, given,

```
const foo = (
  <Foo
    bar={bar}
  />
);
```

**Having defined `foo` like above,** Can I later expand the prop list of `foo` programmatically to **include** `baz`? i.e. as if I did the following **to begin with?**

```
const foo = (
  <Foo
    bar={bar}
    baz={baz}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it programatically in the following manner

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
         data: {bar: "bar"}
    }
}
```

And then pass it to you compoenent using spread operator like

```
const foo = (
  <Foo
    {...this.state.data}
  />
);
```

Later if you wan to add another prop you can just update the state `data` to have another property like

```
addData = () => {
    var data = {...this.state.data}
    data["baz"] = "baz"
    this.setState({data})
}
```

And now since you have passed the props `...this.state.data`

you can access them in you child component like `this.props.bar` and `this.props.baz`

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can do one this, instead of passing the values, pass some state object, latter if you want to pass more data just update the state value, automatically that value will get passed to child component.

```
data = {bar: bar};

const foo = (
  <Foo
    bar = {this.state.data}
  />
);
```

Latter change the data to:

```
data = {bar: bar, a: a};
```

Note: If you want to pass hug data then use some architecture like `redux`, don't store that data in state variable.

Check this example:

```js
var Foo = (props) => {
   return(
      <div>
         {props.data.a}
         <br/>
         {props.data.b ? props.data.b : null}
      </div>
   )
}

class App extends React.Component{

   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
          propsData: {a: 1}
      }
      this.click = this.click.bind(this);
   }
   
   click(){
      let propsData = Object.assign({},this.state.propsData);
      propsData.b = 2;
      this.setState({propsData});
   }
   
   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            <Foo data={this.state.propsData}/>
            <p onClick={this.click} style={{marginTop: 100}}>
                Click me pass more data to child
            </p>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Perhaps my question was unclear. Could you see my edit and see if it makes sense? (in bold)

Comment: The answer makes sense. But there is no way to programmatically pass more props to an already defined React component?

Comment: check the updated answer, when you do the changes in state variable updated value will get passed to child, that's the beauty of `React` :)